# Show that x defines a coordinate neighborhood on the upper sheet of the circular cone C

Tags: differential-geometry

> Consider the map $x : U = (0, 2π) \times (0,\infty)\to{\mathbb R}^3$, $(\theta, v) \mapsto (v\cos\theta, v\sin\theta, v).$
>
> a) Show that $x$ defines a coordinate neighborhood on the upper sheet of the circular cone $C$.

This is first part of a question and it is confusing me in the wording. How do you show if something is a coordinate neighborhood? Does it mean check if the 3 conditions hold when checking for a regular surface?

Comment: Yes, you would need to check that $U$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$ and that $x$ is an injective immersion (that is $x$ is injective onto its image, differentiable and its differential has full rank everywhere). The terminology "x defines a coordinate neighborhood" is a bit off. As it is common to me $x$ is a parametrization and $x(U)$ is the coordinate neighborhood.

Comment: @wspin thanks, that what I thought but I wasn't sure. I've never seen it phrased like that before.